# Formatting text in Drupal 7 not working

Tags: theming

I am new in Drupal 7 and I am trying to format my text using CKEditor. I started to create a basic page, I supplied the **Title** since it is a required field, then I put my text inside the body, there is a section in the Body that I want to use `<h1>` to make it look like the page title. So to do this, I clicked `Heading 1` from the `Format` drop-down. On my editor the text now looks bigger, but when I tried to save it the `<h1>` tag was not implemented. I also tried to style my text using css but it didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the text format as **Full HTML**, text format select list will available below the body text area.

If the text format is specified as **Plain text**, then it will remove the html tags.

You can find out more information and best practices here - [Specifying the allowed formats for user input](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/filter)